# Participle phrase at the end of the sentence

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, modifiers, participles, appositives

When participle phrase comes at the end of the sentence, it usually modifies the subject.

> 1 He smiled nervously with a chocolate in his hands, thinking that the end
>   has come.

Here, participle phrase "thinking that  the end has come"modifies "he", not hands. What I want to ask is, is it OK to put a participle phrase that would modify "hands"?

> 2 He smiled nervously with a chocolate in his hands, darkened with
>   sweetness.

Here, I meant to make past participle phrase "darkened with sweetness" modify his hands.

The reason I am asking is because I realized that participle phrases can be used in the position of appositives:

> 3 His hands, darkened with sweetness, were holding a chocolate.

So does my sentence 2 work in the same way as the sentence 3, or is it impossible to use sentence 2 at all? Is it OK to use sentence 2?

Comment: 3 is not an appositive, but rather a reduced relative clause.  But sure, 2 is fine.  If you'd like to remove all ambiguity, make the clause restrictive:  "He smiled nervously with a chocolate in hands darkened with sweetness."

Comment: Is the non-restrictive version, the sentence 2, a little ambiguous to you?

Comment: No, the semantic cues do it for me.